# Getting OutOfMemoryException when load a document with Microsoft.Office.Interop from IIS website

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, office-interop, office-automation

I have a .NET Core 6 web api that use Office interop to open a ppt document and convert it to pdf.
The application does not have problems when i debug it or when i publish it as a standalone application and run the .exe manually.
I need to publish the web api on IIS on a windows server but when i do i obtain the following error when try to call the api endpoint: "System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program".

This is the method that made the conversion, exception is thrown by "pptApplication.Presentations.Open(originalPptPath, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse)"

```
        public static bool PowerPointToPdf(string originalPptPath, string pdfPath)
        {
            PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = null;
            PowerPoint.Presentation pptPresentation = null;

            object unknownType = Type.Missing;
            var result = false;

            //start power point 
            pptApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();

            //open powerpoint document
            pptPresentation = pptApplication.Presentations.Open(originalPptPath, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

            if (pptPresentation == null)
                return false;

            pptPresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfPath, PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatType.ppFixedFormatTypePDF, PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatIntent.ppFixedFormatIntentPrint);
            result = true;


            // Close and release the Document object.
            if (pptPresentation != null)
            {
                pptPresentation.Close();
                ReleaseObject(pptPresentation);
                pptPresentation = null;
            }

            pptApplication.Quit();
            ReleaseObject(pptApplication);
            pptApplication = null;

            return result;
        }
```

I already tried to change the application pool identity with an admin user but nothing changed. I am aware that microsoft discourages the use of server-side office automation, i have already evaluated several libraries that don't use office automation to make the conversion, but the final result is qualitatively inferior.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right avenue - Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Microsoft strongly recommends that developers find alternatives to Automation of Office if they need to develop server-side solutions. Because of the limitations to Office's design, changes to Office configuration are not enough to resolve all issues. Microsoft strongly recommends a number of alternatives that do not require Office to be installed server-side, and that can perform most common tasks more efficiently and more quickly than Automation. Before you involve Office as a server-side component in your project, consider alternatives.

If you are dealing only with open XML documents in PowerPoint you may consider using the Open XML DSK for dealing with documents or converting them to another file format, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.

Or just consider using any third-party components designed for the server-side execution.